# Matlab Permutation Function

Tags: matlab, permutation

How do I implement the following permutation (from Mathematica) in Matlab?

```
Column[April2Options]
'20150402', 2150., 'C' 
'20150402', 2155., 'C' 
'20150402', 2160., 'C' 
'20150402', 2165., 'C' 
'20150402', 2170., 'C' 
'20150402', 2175.,'C' 
'20150402', 1935., 'P' 
'20150402', 1945., 'P' 
'20150402', 1950., 'P' 
'20150402', 1955., 'P' 
'20150402', 1960., 'P'

April2OptionsPermutations =  Permutations[April2Options, {4}];
```

When I try 'perms' in Matlab:

```
>> perms(April2Options)
Error using perms (line 23)
Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.
```

My data was in an array of structs. Then I tried with a table.

Comment: Not knowing any Mathematica: What would be the output of `April2OptionsPermutations`?

Comment: What are all those unknown characters ?

Comment: Could you edit your post to make all the characters are readable?

Comment: `perms` accepts a numeric vector and it gives you all possible permutations of that vector.  Instead of showing MATLAB users Mathematica code where... probably most of us... will **not** know what it's doing, could you describe in *plain* English what you want accomplished?

Comment: I'd like Matlab to output an array of structs (M x 4) where each row

Comment: permutation of the structure (e.g. expiration, strike price, type).  E.g. ['20150402',2150.,'C','20150402',2155.,'C',
'20150402', 2160., 'C', '20150402', 2165. 'C']

Comment: OK, "array of structs" and `M x 4` contradict each other.  Do you have a 1D array of structs where **each element** is a structure with 4 fields, or do you have a `M x 4` array, where each element is an attribute (string, float, etc.)?  If it's the latter, do you have a **cell** array?  BTW, please add more information to your post.  It isn't our job to continually ask you questions about your problem when you should be the one providing all of the information in the beginning.

Comment: each element is a structure with 4 fields

Comment: Ah OK. That's easy. Give me a few moments

Answer (score 0):

Now that I know what you're really after, `April2Options` is a **structure** array where each element consists of 4 fields.  If I am interpreting your comments correctly, you simply wish to shuffle each structure around in the array.  Use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) for that:

```
April2Options_Perm = April2Options(randperm(numel(April2Options));
```

`randperm` takes in a positive integer `N` and it returns a vector of integers between 1 up to `N` where the order of these integers is shuffled, hence a permutation of values from 1 to `N`.  We can use this output as an index into `April2Options` to shuffle the order and is stored in `April2Options_Perm`.